# summerize NA, count BY GROUP

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

I have this data frame for the test:

```
test_df <- structure(list(plant_sp = c("plant_1", "plant_1", "plant_2", "plant_2", "plant_3",
                                       "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_3", "plant_4", 
                                       "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4", "plant_4",
                                       "plant_5", "plant_5", "plant_5", "plant_5", "plant_5"), 
                          sp_rich = c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 
                                      1, 0, 0, NA, 0,
                                      0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                                      0, NA, NA, 0,NA)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame", 
                     .Names = c("plant_sp", "sp_rich"))
```

I want to create a new data frame that has a sammerize data out of this data:

[image: the df I need]

which indicates the count and NA in **each group** (for example in group plant_1 there are only 2 "1" in the group and 0 "NA"

can you help me?
thanks
Ido

Comment: did you mean for plant_5 count to equal 0, not 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>%
  group_by(plant_sp) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(sp_rich > 0 & !is.na(sp_rich)),
            miss = sum(is.na(sp_rich)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  plant_sp count  miss
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 plant_1      2     0
2 plant_2      1     1
3 plant_3      1     2
4 plant_4      2     0
5 plant_5      0     3
```

Comment: Not sure, but OP may be looking for `count = sum(na.omit(sp_rich))`?

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure what OP is actually looking for either, but you're right that my solution should match the OP's posted desired output. I've edited my solution to reflect that

Comment: you got it right. worked perfect. thanks alot again

Answer (score 2):

Very close to **@latlio** but using reshaping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- test_df %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(is.na(sp_rich),'miss','count')) %>%
  group_by(plant_sp,Var) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=N) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   plant_sp [5]
  plant_sp count  miss
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 plant_1      2     0
2 plant_2      1     1
3 plant_3      3     2
4 plant_4      6     0
5 plant_5      2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(test_df)[, .(count = sum(na.omit(sp_rich) > 0), miss = sum(is.na(sp_rich))), plant_sp]
   plant_sp count miss
1:  plant_1     2    0
2:  plant_2     1    1
3:  plant_3     1    2
4:  plant_4     2    0
5:  plant_5     0    3
```